# GWT,Smart GWT,GWT-ext comparison

Tags: java, spring, gwt, architecture, smartgwt

I am using GWT 2.0.3 with ext in my application.This project is no longer under active development and has been superseded by Smart GWT.I am using HMVC pattern for this application.
Now with existing GWT 2.0.3 and ext version I am getting many issues.Issues are related to the followinng things.

Browser Compatibility
HTML 5 Compliance

Mobile Compatibility

Resolution Independence

Loading Speed

Control Richness

Fews days back GWT 2.3 version also released.Now I want to move my application application to new technology.as ext is no longer under active development.and I also I am getting many issues with existing version.

I am thinking to analyz GWT 2.3, Smart GWT and Spring framework according ot requirement.But still I am bit confused what to do in this situation.If any one has idea about this situaion and give me some clear idea or comparison of technologies then It will very help ful for me.

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding migrating -
It wont be easy to migrate over to your existing code to plain gwt 2.3. ext uses different framework and classes that you will not find in the same way in gwt, you will have to end up re-coding A LOT of the things.

If you want to re-code, then the options are open to you-

- Smart GWT is being actively developed and has a richer classier set of widgets for sure. However, I find the LGPL version documentation lacking and confusing, (if you go for the paid version then not an issue)
- GWT 2.3 on the other hand has got mostly all widgets comparable to smartgwt (still missing stuff like inbuilt validation etc). I find it much lighter and more optimized than smartgwt. However, you may have to do a little more css work to get it looking as classy as smartgwt.

If you want an agressive set of good looking widgets, don't mind a slightly heavy application, go with smart gwt. If you have time to code functionality and design urself, prefer a light application, go with gwt.

EDIT -

- Browser compatibility

  GWT- Very comprehensive, may face a little css niggles here and there.

  Smart GWT- Fairly comprehensive, however, I have had to modify code etc to accomodate different versions of IE. ALSO - do not mix Smart GWT with GWT widgets!!! Its a compatibility nightmare, smartgwt isnt exactly an extension of gwt (smartgwt wraps a lot of native js code). You may end up seeing weird js errors which even the smartgwt team finds hard to debug - their advice - dont mix the widgets.
- Mobile Compatibility

  I have not worked on this aspect, however both are JS based and so should run on any mobile. You may have to figure out UI design elements and capturing natural touch events. Here I would still go with gwt for that fact that it is lighter. Maybe this will help - http://traceurl.blogspot.com/2010/11/state-of-gwt-for-mobile.html Not sure what support smart gwt has for specific mobile events.
- Resolution Independence

  Here Smart gwt wins hands down. Just declare widget sizes in %ages and let it do its magic. Not so straightforward with gwt where if you want resizability - you will have to capture resize events
- Loading speed

  GWT definitely is lighter and loads faster. You can also improve the loading speed of smart gwt, but you will have to work a little for that by deselecting code you dont use etc etc. If you are experienced in that, you may bring down the speed difference to negligible amounts.
- Control Richness

  Not sure what you are asking for, but if its richness of widget functionality, I will go with Smargwt (that is one thing that makes it heavier sadly).

Comment: I am not going to re code.I just want to build new requirement with more functionality and facility.And also want to keep all the point (which are in above description) in mind.

Comment: Can you give more comparison over GWT2.3 and smart GWT over following points:Browser Compatibility HTML 5 Compliance
Mobile Compatibility
Resolution Independence
Loading Speed
Control Richness

Comment: Hey Bhat Thank you very much.Really this will be very helpful for me.

Comment: Bhat some of your comments are a little strange - no adjustments are needed for different versions of IE with SmartGWT, however, a common mistake is to incorporate third-party CSS styles, which can interfere with any HTML content (not just SmartGWT's widgets) - this we cover in the FAQ: http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=8159#aVisual     As far as general confusion, we find that 95% of the time someone says something like this, they just haven't read the QuickStart Guide:  http://www.smartclient.com/product/documentation.jsp

Comment: @Charles - Agree, 3rd party CSS in smartgwt is a total no go. But even without that, I have faced layout issues (sometimes performance issues too!) with Smart GWT between IE 6, 7, 8. But must add that was with version 2.1. Have not updated my projects to later versions.

Comment: You can use whatever 3rd party CSS you like with SmartGWT so long as you do not specifically apply styles to *every* TD, DIV, SPAN, etc - which is very bad practice and won't work with any other framework either.  And again, we have no bug reports of IE layout issues with the core framework - if you think you've found one, feel free to submit a test case.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're willing to take an obvious back-step in functionality and visual appeal, you should go with SmartGWT.  For one, GWT-Ext's grids are radically more powerful & usable than GWT core grids, consider just column resizing and reordering for starters.  For side-by-side comparison:

http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable

http://www.gwt-ext.com/demo/#gridGrouping

In contrast SmartGWT's grids are a radical step up in functionality from GWT-Ext's - I'll just point to one sample but really you need to go through all the folders of grid examples to see the power and breadth of functionality:

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_summaries

So - remember you're building an application for end users, and think about how they will perceive the downgraded UI.

Full disclosure - what I've said above should be self-evidently true, at the same time, SmartGWT is my technology.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a relatively complex GWT project at the moment, and I'm quite happy using GWT 2.3 exclusively. While SmartGWT has much more sophisticated widgets than GWT, you still can't use Uibinder in conjunction with it, which is why I rejected using SmartGWT.

This way, you will have to put a little bit more effort into styling your widgets using CSS, on the other hand it greatly decouples your programming logic from your presentation and greatly speeds up development. Besides, you could concentrate on the logic and let a designer layout/style your application.