# Selection of frame work for a Java Application

Tags: java, hibernate, architecture

I am going to work on an complex application.Application is about to create lakhs of form dynamically, on those form rules can be apply dynamically and transactions of that forms.

For this application points that must be keep in mind are below:

1.Fast Loading:

1.1 Intial application load time must be smaller.

1.2 As there are lacs of forms then controls many in count of lakhs of lakhs with all properties.So while fetching forms from DB it should be fast.

2.Control Richness:

Which ever frame work used, It should be rich in controls, Control like:Date, Date Time Picker, Grid,TextBox,TextAera,Combox etc.

3.Browser Comapibilty

It should be compatible with all browser.

4.Resolution Indepedance

Application should be resolution independent.i.e It should work for every resolution and for every browser.

5.Mobile Compatibility

For this purpose I just started with a demo application.For this I selected GWT2.0.3 + gwt-ext,Hibernate

Hibernate is satisfying all the need regarding back end.But I am not satisfied with GWT as there loading issues,Browser issuse.

So I just need assistance for selecting frame work.Please also suggest me about the pattern 
i.e. MVP,MVC.
I also searched abut spring framework But not much aware of it.
So please suggest me regarding this.

Comment: What do you mean by lacs ? In french, I would tend to think you speak about lakes, but in english, I'm rather confused ...

Comment: Am I correct to think that you're targetting a web-only environment ? (as opposed to a Swing/JavaFX/SWT one)

Comment: It is Lakhs ,hope u will get it...A lakh is a unit in the Indian numbering system equal to one hundred thousand

Comment: Λάκης (Lakhs) is also a Greek first name!

Comment: 1 lakh = 100,000
(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am surprised you found issues with GWT. Personally I feel, it is one of the cleanest front-end implementations. (did you face issues integrating it with hybernate maybe?)

Anyways, another framework that is java style based (extends gwt and is richer) is *Smart GWT* that you can look into. I did a detailed comparison here which answers your questions - [GWT,Smart GWT,GWT-ext comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262003/gwt-smart-gwt-gwt-ext-comparison/6262128#6262128)

If you are not looking for a java style based front end, you should look at jQuery too. http://jquery.com/. It even has a version optimized for touch http://jquerymobile.com/

EDIT -

1) You could even look at flex, which is a flash based. http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/

2) Also, if web based forms is the major area, look at Grails http://www.grails.org/

Comment: For hibernate I didn't get any issues with integration.Basically I am getting issues of loading time,browser compatibly,and Resolution.If you have any hint regarding it please share it.One I found for load timing is code split for gwt and only load necessary code.

Comment: Gwt loads much slower in dev mode as compared to its compiled version. (hope you havent considered dev mode load times here). Code splitting is a really good solution for sure. Resolution wise, I prefer to initialize the application based on the window size, and then not allow my window to application to resize (like gmail). You can achieve resizability using window resize events. Which browsers are you testing on? and what are the issues. Guess that can be another question.

Answer (score 1):

Point 1. Since you consider using Hibernate try "Extra‐lazy" collection fetching and lazy attribute fetching. The elements of the collection are accessed from the database as needed. I think it is a configuration issue to start up faster.

You will probably get faster startup if you use JDBC instead, but Hibernate will cut a lot of development time.

Also the JavaScript files containing your client application may take a lot of initial time to load, so split your application in smaller parts.

and 2. GWT covers your Control Richness issues and gives you a fairly reasonable Browser Compatibility. Gives you everything you have in a desktop Java Application.

About "all browsers": You can not have GUI Richness and Netscape 1.0 compatibility. JavaScript was not invented before Netscape 2.0

Comment: Thanks for reply.For hibernate side I am not getting any issues,it is much better than JDBC as it will help you a lot while developing. About code split can you give any practical of how to de that?

Comment: Take a look at this link. I think it this is what you need: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html